# Windows Phone TwoWay binding not working

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, binding, windows-phone

Actually the 2 way binding works, but there is a problem.

I have a button on the appbar. Also I have a textbox with TwoWay binding. Now, if I am typing in the textbox, and I remove focus from the textbox (close the keyboard by pressing back key), then the Property to which the textbox text is binded gets updated.

But, if I press the AppBar Button without closing the keyboard, the property does not get updated.

Is there a simple solution to this problem?

All help is greatly appreciated.
Thank You!

Edit:
I tried this.focus on the AppBar button click, but still no luck

Edit 2:

Here is my code-

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Title" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}" Margin="15,0,0,0"/>
    <TextBox Name="TitleTB" Text="{Binding Title, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <TextBlock Text="Description" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}" Margin="15,0,0,0"/>
    <TextBox Name="DescriptionTB" Text="{Binding Description, Mode=TwoWay}" AcceptsReturn="True" MaxHeight="300" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
</StackPanel>
```

.cs code-

```
public CreateTaskPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        M1 = new MyClass { Description = "Description", Title = "title1" };
        this.DataContext = M1;
    }
private void ApplicationBarIconButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //save - I change the text in the textbox from title1 to title123 suppose
        // But it still shows title1 if I click the appbar button without closing the keyboard
        this.Focus();

        MessageBox.Show(M1.Title);
    }
```

Edit 3:
MyClass code-

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string title;

    private string description;

    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set
        {
            title = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Title");
        }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get { return description; }
        set
        {
            description = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Description");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant xaml and c# code you are using?

Comment: just share some code.

Comment: @Gavin shared code. Please check updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void ApplicationBarIconButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        BindingExpression expression = TitleTB.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
        MessageBox.Show("Before UpdateSource, Test = " + M1.Title);
        expression.UpdateSource();
        MessageBox.Show("After UpdateSource, Test = " + M1.Title);
}
```

For more Refrence about binding you can go here [Data binding for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/cc278072%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure, did you properly declare the property of MyClass like below?

```
class MyClass {
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Plus, for TwoWay binding, MyClass should implments INotifyPropertyChanged interface to hook up the value changes. [Check example here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/cc278072(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: Please check the updated question - I have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you shift the focus from textbox to some other control in the click event of the ApplicationBarIconButton.